# Invalid Hook Call Error when using Material UI in ReactJS Web App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-hooks, material-ui

**Context**: This page uses ReactJS to list a series of cards (rows) with information about people (screenshot below). Each one of these cards has a "Details" button that would expand into a pop-up modal (Material UI) that displays more information about the person.

[image: Page Screenshot]

**Problem**: Whenever the "Details" button is clicked, I am being prompted with the following error. The button calls the "DetailedModal" function below "TutorCard" function, located in the same file.
[image: Invalid Hook Error]. I believe that this could be either (1) or (3) as suggested by the error above.

**Code**:

```
import React from "react";
// import {ExpandedTutorCard} from "./ExpandedTutorCard.js"
import Button  from '@mui/material/Button';
// import ExpandedTutorCard from "./ExpandedTutorCard.js";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';
import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';
import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';
import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

 function TutorCard({ first_name, last_name, grade, subject}) {
    return (
        <div className="md:flex bg-white shadow text-gray-800 my-4 py-4 px-10 rounded-md items-center justify-between hover:bg-gray-300"  >
            {/* <img
                style={{ maxWidth: "60px"}}
                className="rounded-full shadow-md border border-gray-300"
                src={image}
                alt="employee"
            /> */}
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center"}}>{first_name}</p>
            <p className="font text-md" style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{last_name}</p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{grade}</p>
            <p style={{ color: 'black', textAlign: "center" }}>{subject}</p>
            <Button onClick={DetailedModal}> Details </Button> //Calls "DetailedModal"
        </div>
    )
}


const BootstrapDialog = styled(Dialog)(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiDialogContent-root': {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  '& .MuiDialogActions-root': {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

function BootstrapDialogTitle(props) {
  const { children, onClose, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <DialogTitle sx={{ m: 0, p: 2 }} {...other}>
      {children}
      {onClose ? (
        <IconButton
          aria-label="close"
          onClick={onClose}
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 8,
            top: 8,
            color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
          }}
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
    </DialogTitle>
  );
}

BootstrapDialogTitle.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function DetailedModal() { //called when "Details" button
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open dialog
      </Button>
      <BootstrapDialog
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
        open={open}
      >
        <BootstrapDialogTitle id="customized-dialog-title" onClose={handleClose}>
          Modal title
        </BootstrapDialogTitle>
        <DialogContent dividers>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
            dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
            consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
            Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom>
            Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus
            magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec
            ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
          </Typography>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button autoFocus onClick={handleClose}>
            Save changes
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </BootstrapDialog>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TutorCard;
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "tutors-information",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.12.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@trimbleinc/modus-react-bootstrap": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "mdb-react-ui-kit": "^6.0.0",
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.6",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
    "u": "^0.1.0",
    "uid": "^2.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.8.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.8.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set PORT=3008 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^18.0.4"
  }
}
```

I had already tried implementing the workarounds found on almost every other StackOverFlow question for this error, however none of it seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: You are passing `DetailedModal` as the `onClick` function for a button. So rather than rendering the dialog, it will instead execute that function as the click handler and that function in turn calls `React.useState` which violates the rules of hooks because you aren't in a component at that point.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for your response. I am new to this, so please let me know what else I should pass to onClick for this to work?

Comment: I recommending looking through the [examples in the docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/). Typically the `onClick` will execute a function that sets state to trigger opening the dialog.